# How to troubleshoot, {Error=ExecutableTwiddleFailed}

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator

I have an iOS app that I have been working on for some time, but for some reason it stopped working in the Simulator today.  I checked the Simulator log file, CoreSimulator.log and it is giving me an error message similiar to what I posted in the title, "{Error=ExecutableTwiddleFailed}"  If you feel so adventours you can clone the project, and try to build it yourself, and you'll see what it is I am describing.  As of right now, the only thing I can think of is that the Info.plist file got jacked up somehow, but I have no idea.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://github.com/ipatch/kegcop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this error message because all the `.m` files from the `Build Phases` -> `Compile Sources` were removed.  I ended up adding both the `.h` and `.m` files to the `Compile Sources` which ended up giving me a bunch of compiler warnings, so long story short you to only add the `.m` files because the `.h` files are included at the top of the `.m` file.  I hope this helps future visitors.